# Celery with SQS broker & dead letter queue

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to figure out how can I configure celery to move a message once it passed `max_retries` as configured, to the dead letter queue.

Currently it is deleting (acks) the message once exceeded `max_retries`.

Is there such an option?

Comment: What do you mean by "moving" it? To another queue? Re-scheduling it at another time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, as far as I know, this is not possible but soon Celery [should be able to do it](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4797). You can already test the branch from the PR mentioned in the Celery issue I linked to and see if it works as you expect.

Comment: this PR https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/4970 was merged and released as far as I understand, and it implements a different feature than requested.

Comment: it implements a flag that prevents a task to be acked once it failed. this will not result in placing the message in the DLQ.

Comment: yep "After the visibility timeout this would go back to the queue. After n receives with no ack, sqs will automatically push it into the dead letter queue "

Comment: Isn't that what you want? - To eventually end up in the DLQ.

Comment: This implementation is based on SQS visibility timeout, not on actual celery retries.
which acts accordingly to what is configured in the AWS console, not what is configured with celery max_retries

Comment: I understood it completely differently. After the configured number of retries, the task will get no ack, and then SQS will eventually move it to the DLQ. I could have misunderstood it...

Comment: celery prevents the ack, then SQS will requeue the message (the dangerous part) after visibility timeout. after max (SQS) retries, it will move it to the DLQ

Answer (score 0):

following DejanLekic answer, I have created a dockerised project with local SQS demonstrating the solution he purposed

It can be seen here https://github.com/galCohen88/celery_sqs_redis_backend

Answer (score 0):

in Celery version `celery = {extras = ["sqs"], version = "^5.3.4"}` you can stick to the next approach:

- [retry](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) your task using raise `Task.retry(max_retries=5)` (just do not pass retrying exception argument here)
- after all the retries have been exceeded you will be raised with [MaxRetriesExceededError](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/reference/celery.exceptions.html#celery.exceptions.MaxRetriesExceededError)
- catch `MaxRetriesExceededError` and `raise` [Reject](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#reject) with `requeue=False`.
  And eventually the task will be redrived to SQS DLQ